# Why won't my comparison array work?

Tags: javascript

I am building a game that I want to take player inputs from prompts for, and compare them to inputs they have already used, and reject the choice if they choose the same thing twice.  Here is my relevant code:

```
var playerChoiceRow = 0;
var playerChoiceColumn = 0;
var playerAttackArray = [];

function playerAttack(playerChoiceRow,playerChoiceColumn) {
for (var i=0; i<playerAttackArray.length; i++){
    if ([playerChoiceRow,playerChoiceColumn] === playerAttackArray[i]){
        alert("You have already attacked this space, please choose another.");
        playerChoiceRow = prompt("Please choose a number between 0 and 5.");
        playerChoiceColumn = prompt("Please choose a number between 0 and 5.");
    }
}
if (playerChoiceRow === undefined){
    alert("Please choose a number between 0 and 5!");
    playerChoiceRow = prompt("Please choose a number between 0 and 5.");
}
if (playerChoiceColumn === undefined){
    alert("Please choose a number between 0 and 5!");
    playerChoiceColumn = prompt("Please choose a number between 0 and 5.");
}
playerAttackArray.push([playerChoiceRow,playerChoiceColumn]);

while (playerCounter || computerCounter <=4){
    var playerChoiceRow = prompt("Please select row of attack. (0 though 5)")-'';
    var playerChoiceColumn = prompt("Please select column of attack. (0 though 5)")-'';
    playerAttack(playerChoiceRow,playerChoiceColumn);
    if (playerCounter == 5){
        alert("You have sunk all enemy boats!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Does the fact that `[1,2] === [1,2]` is false in JS answer your question, Havamere? (Not sure I understand it.)

Comment: That fact doesn't help the situation I've caused.  I could show the full code, but I want to build this on my own as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript array comparison is about identity, not content; in other words `===` between two expressions when they're arrays returns true only if they are referring to the very same array object, not if they're two arrays containing the same things.

You could work around this problem by converting both sides to strings first:

```
if (""+[playerChoiceRow,playerChoiceColumn] === ""+playerAttackArray[i]) ...
```

Comment: Ok, so if I only used == would that then accept as true?  The point of the issue right now, is that if a person were to input an array that caused a "Hit", they could simply enter that in an additional 4 times and with the game.  It is basically a battleship style game on a 2D array.  I am certainly willing to work with the quotation marks if i need to.

Comment: @Havamere: using `==` wouldn't solve because it's the same as `===` when the two expressions are of the same type. The difference is only that `==` does a type conversion when types are different (`===` instead just returns `false`).

Comment: Got it, I applied the parenthesis and it worked, sort of. Unfortunately, because of the way I wrote the code, if the same array entry (say [5,5]), is entered more times than the length of the array, it still accepts it.  Would the forEach method be more appropriate here? Something to say that it will not accept and entry if it is already present in the array?

Comment: @Havamere: I'd probaly go for a dictionary instead. You start wih `taken={}` and do `taken[row+"/"+col]=1` for each move. Before accepting a move if `taken[row+"/"+col]===1` then the move is not valid... This way you don't need to make a loop.

Comment: hrmm, using an object table as a reference was not something I had thought of.  It will take a some more research on my end.  This is part of an entrance application, so I want to be able to understand all of my code.  I'm still fairly new to programming as a whole, but I do feel I'm getting a decent had at it.  I have to make a change in my career, and i'm enjoying overcoming these programming problems.